# tensorflow matrix_band_part function equivalent in pytorch

Tags: indexing, pytorch

I need to create upper triangular masking tensor in pytorch. in tensorflow it's easy using [matrix_band_part](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/band_part).  is it any pytorch equivalent for this function?
it's like numpy triu_indices but I need for tensor, not just matrix.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Only the batch wise version is now part of official PyTorch implementation.